# Why does two way binding not update directives controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In line with John Papa's [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) I have update my directive to use the ControllerAs syntax. However after doing this, my directive did not update when changes were made to the variable the directive was bound to.

i.e. when mainCtrl.rules is updated, the value of ctrl.rules is not updated

To solve this I had to create a watch in the link function that updates the ctrl.rules variable when $scope.rules changes.

Why is this - are the directive and controller not on the same scope?

HTML

```
<div my-directive rules="mainCtrl.rules"></div>
```

JS - Main Ctrl

```
rulesService.get().then(mainCtrl.rules = response.rules;);
```

JS - Directive

```
(function () {

    angular.module('myModule')
        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

        myDirective.$inject = [];

        function myDirective()
        {
            var directive = {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    rules: '='
                },
                controller: 'myCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                templateUrl: "/Template/myDirective",
                transclude: true,
                link: linkFunc
            };

            return directive;
        };

        angular.module('myModule')
            .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

        myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

        function myCtrl($scope)
        {
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.rules = $scope.rules;
            ctrl.showRules = false;
            ctrl.toggleShowRules = toggleShowRules;

            function toggleShowRules() {
                ctrl.showRules = !ctrl.showRules;
            };
        };

        function linkFunc($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl)
        {
            //watch the rules collection on the directive and update controller if it changes
            $scope.$watch("rules", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue != oldValue)
                {
                    ctrl.rules = newValue;
                }
            });
        };
})();
```

TEMPLATE

```
   <div class="rules" ng-show="rules.length > 0">
        <ul ng-show="ctrl.showRules">
            <li ng-repeat="rule in ctrl.rules" class="rule-details">
                <p>{{rule.title}}</p>                               
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you are going to down vote, please at least give a comment as to why. Constructive feedback please.

Comment: `controllerAs` is really meant for giving your controller a name so that you can access it in your templates.  So the way your using it is incorrect.

Comment: updated to show this is in fact what I am doing

Comment: how are you updating `mainCtrl.rules`? if in your `mainCtrl` your doing `mainCtrl.rules = newData` then the 2-way binding will not work. Because then `ctrl.rules` will be reference the old data and `$scope.rules` will be referencing the new data, hence you need the watch in your link function.

Comment: try `angular.copy(response.rules, mainCtrl.rules);`

Comment: @harish I don't see why `angular.copy` would help.  It not only doesn't help but it actually hurts to make copies when you want the `mainCtrl.rules` reflect any changes that were made.

Comment: @T.V. thanks for comments. It appears I do not understand two way binding very well. Are you able to suggest a way to implement this that does not require the watch? I know I can do this be placing everything in the link function. But i like the idea of having the logic in an easily tested controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your link function `$scope` is not the provider it's the isolate `scope` of the into the directive, so I think what you have is a ctrl where `this` is not the scope of the directive but it's the constructor.

I think if you do something like this you will see the difference.

```
function myCtrl($scope, $attrs, $log) {

   this.scope = $scope;

   $log.debug(this);
   // vs
   $log.debug(this.scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

The offending piece of code is `ctrl.rules = $scope.rules;` in `myCtrl` this will point to the existing list of rules. Then when `rulesService.get().then(mainCtrl.rules = response.rules;);` occurs, it set's the `$scope.rules` in your directive to point to your new data however `ctrl.rules` is still pointing to the old list.  There's 2 ways to fix this without major changes to your code.

**Option 1**: Instead of replace the reference in your `mainCtrl` you can update it like so:

```
mainCtrl.rules.length = 0;
angular.extend(mainCtrl.rules, response.rules);
```

That option is somewhat expensive though since there is looping involve to get your reference updated with the new values.

**Option 2**: Instead of setting `ctrl.rules` to references `$scope.rules` you can create a function that return the `$scope.rules` so instead of `ctrl.rules = $scope.rules` you can do the following:

```
ctrl.getRules = function () { return $scope.rules; }
```

then in your template change your `ng-repeat` to

```
<li ng-repeat="rule in ctrl.getRules()" class="rule-details">
```

Option 2 is somewhat easier to understand while option 1 is harder to understand to someone besides you who's trying to read the code.